# adding two three dimensional numpy array:

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy array : X shape is (68,44,13) and X_toadd shape is: (68,44,7)I want to add them together in a way that I will  have X_new shape as (68,44, 20). So, I need to keep the first two dimensions of X and add the 7 columns from X_toadd's third dimension to the 13 columns.
how should I do that?

add, append, and concatenate are tried but the result is not what I want which should have the shape (68,44,20)!

Comment: Do you have a lot of 3-dimensional arrays where you only want to add together the 3rd value of each of them? Or do you want to keep the first two values as they are because they happen to be equal?
In either case, it's probably easiest to define a function that will do what you wish by accessing the specific indexes of your arrays and add them or leave them as they are.

Comment: the code shared below does what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which axis to use to glue things together.
Here, -1 denotes the first axis from the the back.

```
import numpy as np
a,b = np.zeros((68,44,13)), np.zeros((68,44,7))

c = np.concatenate([a,b], axis=-1)

c.shape
(68, 44, 20)
```

Comment: This code gave me the exact result that I needed! Thank you so much